# Need help for fancy theorems using mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, mdframed

I've been working with LaTex for a while and with Tikz I've done stuff nothing fancy just things for homework but now I will write my thesis I want some elegant cool theorem box using mdframed and this is my code for the thing I have done

```
\documentclass{book}
{\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
 \mdfdefinestyle{Teorema}{
    frametitlerule=false,
    linecolor=black,%FireBrick
    linewidth=1pt,
    innerlinewidth =1pt,
    frametitlerulewidth=2pt, 
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!40,%DarkSalmon
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
    skipbelow=15pt,
    }
\mdtheorem[style=Teorema]{teorema}{Teorema}}
```

what should I modify in my code in order to get something like this

[image]

I read the `mdframed` manual but really I don't why they use some commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}%
  {colback=white,colframe=blue!50,fonttitle=\bfseries,
   enhanced,
   coltitle=blue!75!black,
   attach boxed title to top left=
     {xshift=2ex,yshift=-2mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
   boxed title style={colframe=blue!50,
     colback=blue!50}}{th}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
    This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
    in this example, prefixed with the section number. This theorem is numbered with
    \ref{th:theoexample} and is given on page \pageref{th:theoexample}.
  \end{mytheo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is the example from `mdframed` manual modified so that it compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%% the following is commaon for all examples in mdframed manual
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
%%% upto here
\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
 {\mdfsetup{%
   frametitle={%
    \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
         {\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
 }%
{\mdfsetup{%
  frametitle={%
   \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
   \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
        {\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
 }%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
       linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
       frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
        \ExampleText
    \end{theo}
    \begin{theo}
        \ExampleText
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All you have to do with above is type your content within `begin{theo}` and `\end{theo}` like

```
\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
    Your content here.   
\end{theo}
```

For example:

```
\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
    An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
        \begin{align}
            L[v] = f,
        \end{align}
    where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is the dependent
    variable, and $f$ is a given non-zero function of the independent
    variables alone.
\end{theo}
```