# How to make a theorem box in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, amsmath, overleaf

Good morning,

Could you tell me how to make this LaTeX box because I can’t :
[image]

Thy

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Can you show us how you're creating your theorem in the first place?

Comment: See similar Example 6  – theorem with separate header and the help of TikZ (complex) of [mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) manual.

Comment: Take a look at `tcolorbox` package too.

Comment: @Clem if the answer below satisfies please accept by ticking the green check mark left side of answer

Comment: @Clem  please upvote and accept if the answer met your expectations

Answer (score 2):

Please see if the answer satisfies your requirement

Referenced from [Need help for fancy theorems using mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233926/need-help-for-fancy-theorems-using-mdframed)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{Theorem}{%
                            colback=white, 
                            colframe=blue!70,
                            fonttitle=\bfseries,
                            enhanced, 
                            sharp corners,
                            coltitle=blue!75!black,
                            attach boxed title to top left={%
                                            xshift=2ex,
                                            yshift=-4mm,
                                            yshifttext=-1mm},
                            boxed title style={%
                                            colframe=white,
                                            colback=white}}
                            {th}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
        This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
        in this example, prefixed with the section number. This theorem is numbered with
        \ref{th:theoexample} and is given on page \pageref{th:theoexample}.
    \end{mytheo}
\end{document}
```

[image]